# Cartodb-Displaying Mode and Averages in Infowindow

Tags: carto

I have some Boolean and string variables that I want to display in the info window on carto db. But it seems to be only showing one individual data point. How do I get it to show modes or averages of the entire data set?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some SQL to make that information available. If you open the SQL tray and change `SELECT * FROM your_table` to:

```
SELECT *, avg(interesting_column) OVER () AS table_avg
FROM your_table
```

Now toggle the new variable on in your infowindow to make it available. Just fill in `interest_column` with the numeric column you want information from, and make sure to update `your_table` with the appropriate name.

Comment: The SQL trick mentioned here is called a _Window Function_ and you can get more details about them [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html). They are really useful!!